# How to run same function multiple times and save as new variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Just as the title says, I am trying to run a function about 30+ times, but with each time running different variables. I am trying to save each time it runs as a different variable because afterwards, different calculations will be ran on them. Here is a sample:

```
first = my_func(name = a, desc = b, ticker = c)
first.dict_name1 = z_score(first.data,12)

second = my_func(name = d, desc = e, ticker = f)
second.dict_name1 = ... (a diff calculation)

third = my_func(.....same process....)


class my_func:

    def __init__(
                 self,
                 name       = [],
                 desc       = '',
                 # tickers can be loaded as a list of strings, or if a custom field is needed it can use a tuple
                 tickers    = [],
                 indicator  = [],
                 signal     = []
                ):
    
        self.name       = name
        self.desc       = desc
        self.tickers    = tickers
    
        self.data       = {}
        self._data      = {}
    
        for ticker in tickers:
        
            # check if the ticker is a tuple, if so call the custom field
            if isinstance(ticker, tuple):
                self.load_data(ticker[0],ticker[1])
            else:
                self.load_data(ticker)

    def load_data(self,ticker, field='PX_LAST'):
    
        self.data[ticker] = bbg.bdh(ticker, fld_list = field, start_date='19300101')
```

Comment: Why do you want it as separate variables? See [How do I create a variable number of variables](//stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/843953)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great use case for loops and lists. A list of lists holds the parameters for each call and they are collected in a results list

```
my_func_table = 
    # name, desc, ticker
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9] ]

results = []
for name, desc, ticker in my_func_table:
    val = my_func(name=name, desc=desc, ticker=ticker)
    val.dict_name1 = z_score(val.data,12)
    results.append(val)
```

You could also associate these results with names. Perhaps a dictionary with the names, the global namespace or even a trivial class that has the name as an attribute.

```
result_names = ["first", "second", etc...]

for var, vals in zip(result_names, my_func_table):
    name, desc, ticker = vals
    val = my_func(name=name, desc=desc, ticker=ticker)
    val.dict_name1 = z_score(val.data,12)
    globals()[var] = val
```

Comment: This would all have them saved under "results". How would i get them saved as separate variables?

Comment: Why save them as separate variables? Is "first" better than `result[0]`? Later, if you plan to process `first`, then `second`, etc... it would be better to have the list.

Comment: hmmm maybe I am missing out a detail about what the function does? I will include it in the post. But when i type `result[0]`, i get `<my_py_tools.my_func at 0x1ec473edc70>`

Comment: That is strange. The example calls the function and it would be more than a little odd if the function returns itself!

Comment: I believe your entire code was correct, user error on my end. I apologize-- still learning python :D

Comment: Okay, looking at the edit, `my_func` is really a class. So, it does make sense. `my_func(...)` instanciates an object of the class and its representation when you print is `<my_py_tools.my_func at 0x1ec473edc70>`. The python style guide says classes should be named like `MyFunc` (and "func" is a lousy name for a class). It helps spot issues like this.

Answer (score 3):

Keep the parameters of each run in a list and iterate over it.

```
lst = [(a, b, c), (d, e, f)]
results = [my_func(name=name, desc=desc, ticker=ticker) for name, desc, ticker in lst]
```

Comment: This would all have them saved under "results"? How would i get them saved as separate variables?

Comment: @worldCurrencies Use unpacking to get a series of variables, like `first, second, ... = results` or `first, second, ... = (my_func(name, desc, ticker) for name, desc, ticker in lst)`, but you must ensure that the number of variables is the same as the number of iterations.